# Find basis vectors of a plane where $Ax+By+Cz\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-geometry

This may be a dumb question.  If so I apologize... I don't consider myself an expert in Linear Algebra by any means.

If I have the equation of a plane where $Ax+By+Cz=D$ and $D\neq 0$, then how do you find the basis?

Normally, you would solve for $Ax=0$ and determine the basis vectors, thus based on the null space basis.  However $D$ is really equivalent to the dot product of a position vector to a known point on the plane and the normal vector.  If this known point is the origin, thus a zero vector, then this makes sense.  But if it's not, then what?  Does $D$ count in somehow?  Should I then use $Ax=b$ and derive the basis based on the Column Space instead of the Null Space?

Comment: Technically, there is only a "basis" for a subspace of a vector space, and that plane, since it does not contain $0$, is not a subspace.

Comment: Yeah, I realize it's not technically a subspace since it doesn't go through the origin, but I am trying to get a grasp on how to treat a plane in a program I'm writing and in normal R3 space, not all planes can be defined at the origin.  Having a basis could be helpful when attempting to compare angles of vectors on a plane (programmatically speaking that is) with reference to a basis vector... I think anyways ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $D\ne0$ then the plane is not a vector space and so the concept of basis is meaningless.

However, you could find a basis $\def\v#1{{\bf#1}}\{\v v_1,\v v_2\}$  for the plane $Ax+By+Cz=0$; then if $\v u$ is one specific vector on your plane, all vectors on the plane will be given by
$$\v u+\lambda_1\v v_1+\lambda_2\v v_2\ ,\quad \lambda_1,\lambda_2\in{\Bbb R}\ .$$

Comment: +1 Alternatively, you can find any three non-co-linear points on the plane and then represent every point on the plane as $a\mathbf v_1+b\mathbf v_2+c\mathbf v_3$ uniquely, under the condition $a+b+c=1$. This is more natural because all the vectors are on the plane.

Comment: It turns out that your u+λ 1 v 1 +λ 2 v 2  ,λ 1 ,λ 2 ∈R  approach is perfect.  If I treat the plane as though it originates at the origin, then I can force D=0 by setting its position vector, u, equal to the zero vector.  Then derive the orthonormal basis vectors I'm looking for, v 1 and v 2.  Any point on the plane can be defined as the sum of the actual (non-zero vector) u I originally had plus the linear combination of the orthonormal basis vectors v 1 and v 2.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**N** = [A,B,C] - normal to plane
**p0** = **N** * D/(A*A + B* B + C*C) - intersection point between normal and plane
**n** = **N** - **p0**
**V1** = [D/A,0,0] - point on plane. If A = 0, we can take other point, e.g.[0,D/B,0] or [0,0,D/C]
**v1** = **V1** - **p0**; first base vector on plane
**v2** = cross(**n**, **v1**) ; second base vector on plane.